# Invalid column name error when adding to Group By

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have this in my Select statement and need to add to my GROUP BY

```
,cast(year(getdate()) as nvarchar(4))+cast(DATEPART(QUARTER,getdate()) as nvarchar(1))+'Q' mQuarter
```

When I add the column mQuarter to the Group by I get an error:

> Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27
>   Invalid column name 'mQuarter'

Comment: Have you shown line 27 of the query?

Answer (score 3):

If you look at [Documentation for SELECT statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/select-transact-sql?view=sql-server-2017), you'll see that the GROUP BY evaluated before the SELECT statement, so any columns that you alias in the SELECT do no exist in GROUP BY. What you need to do is GROUP BY the whole thing:

```
GROUP BY cast(year(getdate()) as nvarchar(4)) +
         cast(DATEPART(QUARTER,getdate()) as nvarchar(1))
```

Answer (score 1):

Since you aren't referencing any of the columns in your tables, you don't need to include mQuarter in your GROUP BY clause. If you remove it, you shouldn't see an error; however, without seeing the rest of your query, I'm not sure it will return the result you're looking for. It will just return 20183Q in every row.

Select statements really begin processing at the FROM clause, and end with the SELECT portion of the statement. Meaning the query is read starting at FROM, then GROUP BY, then WHERE... and SELECT is read last. This means that GROUP BY can only reference columns that exist in your FROM clause. Thus, you get the error message 'Msg 207, Level 16, State 1, Line 27 Invalid column name 'mQuarter', because 'mQuarter' doesn't exist until your SELECT statement.
So essentially, you have to reproduce your 'mQuarter' column in the GROUP BY as well to get it to work.

```sql
GROUP BY cast(year(getdate()) as nvarchar(4))+cast(DATEPART(QUARTER,getdate()) as nvarchar(1))+'Q'
```

Comment: Added the whole column in the Group by and got this error, "Msg 164, Level 15, State 1, Line 27
Each GROUP BY expression must contain at least one column that is not an outer reference."

Comment: @Camille you need to give us the full query text

Comment: As the edit shows - this is an invariant expression so dont need to group by it at all. It will have the same value for every row. Unless getdate() was just used as an example and it actually refers to a column.

Answer (score 0):

Use parentheses.  However, this can get simplified by getting rid of some of the casts:

```
( datename(year, getdate()) +
  datename(quarter, getdate()) +
  'Q'
) as mQuarter
```

`datename()` is a handy function, because it returns a string rather than a number.  The only time you have to be careful is with `month`, because the month name is returned.

Comment: Still getting the same error, when changing to this code.

Comment: @Camille . . . I don't think this code would be causing your syntax error.  You should look at the rest of your code.

Comment: Don't think parenthesis makes any difference. Anyone no differently?